# iphone: rotating flipped view when rotating visible view

Tags: iphone

I have a resizing issue when rotating a view controller that has two views which I switch between using the flip animation.
The problem appears if i do the following steps:

1. Rotate the device when viewing the tableview.
2. Click the info button.
3. Rotate the device (infoView appears stretched).
4. Click on info button (tableview appears stretched)

It appears that the view that is not added to the superview is not resizing correctly, since it was not part of the composite views when the device was rotated.. Is there any way to get this view auto resized correctly?

Below is a code sample

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //background image
    backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-app.png"]];
    backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    [self.view addSubview: backgroundImageView];
    [backgroundImageView release];


    //infoView
    aboutImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"About.png"]];
    aboutImageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    //tableView
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc ] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease ];
    //set the rowHeight once for performance reasons.
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 75;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);                    

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    //set the rowHeight once for performance reasons.
    [self.view addSubview: tableView];
    //[tableView release];

    [self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];//for resizing on rotation

    //info button
    UIButton * infoDarkButtonType = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
    infoDarkButtonType.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0);
    infoDarkButtonType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [infoDarkButtonType addTarget:self action:@selector(infoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonInfo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoDarkButtonType];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonInfo;
    [infoDarkButtonType release];   
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonInfo;
    [buttonInfo release];   

}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;

}


- (void)infoAction:(id)sender{ 
    NSLog(@"Clicked on the info button");


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];     /* Sub. duration here */

    UIView *superview;
    if ((superview = [tableView superview])) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:superview cache:YES];
        [tableView removeFromSuperview];
        [superview addSubview:aboutImageView];
    } else if ((superview = [aboutImageView superview])) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:superview cache:YES];
        [aboutImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [superview addSubview:tableView];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in viewWillAppear:animated. It's called every time your view will appear. View did load is called once.

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

every view inherits it.

Comment: the code relating to the view drawing and auto-resizing that you put in your viewDidLoad method.